# Split appended table up (JQuery or JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending table and I want to have that it only shows 4 trusts at a table, I want to be able to scroll left or right through the table like a carousal.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this? (No extra plugins please)

**How I want the example:**

- Slide/Page1 - Trust 1, Trust 2, Trust 3, Trust 4
- Slide/Page2 - Trust 5, Trust 6, Trust 7, Trust 8
- Slide/Page3 - Trust 9, Trust 10, Trust 11, Trust 12

**My code:**

```js
    var trustIDCount = '';
    var trustData = '[{"trustName":"University Hospitals of Morecambe Bay"},' +
                 '{"trustName":"Taunton and Musgrove"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"St Georges Healthcare"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"The Rotherham"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"City Hospitals Sunderland"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Bradford District Care Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Cental Manchester Foundation Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Kingston Hospital"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Nottingham University Hospital"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Nottingham Health Informatics"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Tameside Hospital"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Your Healthcare"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Hull and East Yorkshire"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Doncaster and Bassettlaw"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Wigan Wrightington and Leigh"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Barnsley Hospital NHS Foundation Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Cornwall Partnership NHS Foundation Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Birmingham Childrens"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Pennine Acute Hospital Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"CarePlus Grp"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Imperial College Healthcare NHS Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Cumbria CCG"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Poole Borough Council"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"InHealth"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Bridgewater Community Healthcare NHS Foundation Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"University Hospitals Coventry and Warwickshire NHS Trust"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Royal London Borough of Greenwich"},'+
                 '{"trustName":"Urgent Care 24"}]';

    var trHTML = '';

    $.each(JSON.parse(trustData), function (i, item) 
    {
        trustIDCount++;
        trHTML += '<tr id=' + trustIDCount + ' class="trClass"><td>' + '<div class="imageWrapper"></div>' + '<div class="textWrapper">' + item.trustName + '</div>' + '</td>';
    });
    $('#trustTable').find("tbody").html(trHTML);
```

```css
#trustTable
{
  width: 100%;
}

.trClass 
{
    direction:rtl;
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.imageWrapper
{
    height: 30px;    
    width: 75px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.textWrapper
{
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    clear:both;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="trustTable">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you try anything ? what is your question? Do you want us to do your job ?

Comment: @Alp Sorry missed the question off. I'm just looking for any recommendation on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have 4 of those trusts per page. And a way to navigate to next or previous pages.

That means that you need to remember the current page number and a mechanism to increment or decrement that value depending on the user's navigation choice. Depending on the current page value, you need to decorate your page with only 4 trusts per page (unless at the last page, on which there might be less than 4 trust, depending on the total number of trusts).

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1s2hzbk/) to give you an idea:and to play with.

```
function previous(){
    if (currentPage>0){
        currentPage --;
        showTable();
    }
}

function next(){
    if (currentPage<Math.floor(htmlArray.length/4) - 1){
        currentPage ++;
        showTable();
    }
}

function showTable(){
    var trHTML = '';
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
       trHTML = trHTML + htmlArray[currentPage * 4 + i];
    }
    $('#trustTable').find("tbody").html(trHTML);

}

...

    var htmlArray = new Array();

var currentPage = 0;
    $.each(JSON.parse(trustData), function (i, item) 
    {
        trustIDCount++;
//        trHTML += '<tr id=' + trustIDCount + ' class="trClass"><td>' + '<div class="imageWrapper"></div>' + '<div class="textWrapper">' + item.trustName + '</div>' + '</td>';
        htmlArray.push('<tr id=' + trustIDCount + 
                       ' class="trClass"><td>' + '<div class="imageWrapper"></div>' + '<div class="textWrapper">' + item.trustName + '</div>' + '</td>');
    });
   // $('#trustTable').find("tbody").html(trHTML);

$("#prev").click(previous);
$("#next").click(function(){next();});

showTable();
```

**__UPDATE__**

```
function next(){
    if (currentPage<Math.floor(htmlArray.length/4) - 1){
        currentPage ++;
    } else {
        currentPage = 0;
    }
    showTable();
}
```

Comment: Alp - How do I have it where you can keep pressing next and it will keep going round the tables pages. example:  `page1 -> page2 -> page3 -> page1 -> page 2 -> page3`

Comment: Got it working for `next()` but not got it for `previous()`

Comment: @ChrisBeckett it is not that complicated. currentPage decides which page to show. So, in the next function, when currentPage gets bigger than currentPage<Math.floor(htmlArray.length/4) - 1, resetting it to zero, should fix the problem. See my update in the answer.

Comment: I've already got the next function. I'm looking for the previous fiction. So if was Page 1 it was go back to Page 3. Like it looping round like carousel

Comment: Similarly, if currentPage is 0 and if user hits previous, reset it to Math.floor(htmlArray.length/4) - 1 and call showTable.

Comment: Cheers Alp! Helped once again :)